# Why is the retainCount is 0 instead of 1?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management

Here is the code. I have tested with NSString, and it return -1. But for NSMutableArray is 0 instead.

```
NSMutableArray *items = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for(int i=0;i<10;i++)
{
    [items addObject:[Possession randomPossession]];
}

/*for(int i=0;i<[items count];i++)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", [items objectAtIndex:i]);
}*/



//Using Fast Enumeration
/*for(items in items)
{
    NSLog(@"%@", items);
}*/


NSLog(@"%d", [items retainCount]);
```

I made mistake by using array in iteration. The correct one should be like this.

```
//Using Fast Enumeration
    for(Possession *item in items)
    {
        NSLog(@"%@", item);
    }
```

And the retainCount is back to normal as expected 1.

Comment: Can you please clarify where your -1 is coming from, and what you mean by 'testing with NSString'? Thanks!

Comment: Does your code really say "for (items in items)"? Because if it does, surely everything's broken. (In particular, "items" doesn't mean the same thing at the end of the code as at the start, and it's not really pointing to an NSMutableArray any more.)

Comment: completely agree with  Gareth McCaughan

Comment: I just create an NSString instance and alloc it, then print the retainCount. Well, it turned out to be -1. As for the for(items in items) it actually works. Perhaps it means like enumerate every item inside the NSMutableArray items?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A) You should never look at `retainCount`, even for debugging. It's an internal implementation detail that can provide confusing results.

B) This:

```
for(items in items)
```

is almost certainly *not* what you mean -- you're using the array object ("items") as the iterator too! Something like:

```
for(Possession *item in items)
```

would make more sense.

---

update:

You might want to look at some of the examples in Apple's [documentation on fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocFastEnumeration.html). You really want to have a separate variable that acts as your loop iterator. What you're doing (`for(items in items)`) sets `items` to each object in the array in turn, and when you exit the loop, `items` will be `nil`!

Comment: I actually practice by trying to fast enumeration by converting from the commented code above. Since I have init the NSMutable array, I don't think there is a need to do (Possession *item in items). CMIIW.

Comment: It seems that I made mistake as you pointed. Can you explain to me why I need to create a new Possession *item for the code above?

Comment: @Sayz Lim, you're not creating a new `Possession *item`... you're just making a new variable in which to store it.

Comment: Oh yeah, I should create a  variable to store the object in the array in order to display it. I misunderstood that part.